# How to increase length of a text file by adding 4065009 spaces using Textpad or Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, text-files, whitespace, textpad, trailing

I need to increase length of 2,00,000 rows by adding trailing spaces of around 4065009 using textpad or notepad++ . How is this possible ? I have tried various options available in Notepad++ like convert tab to space etc it isn't working .

Comment: You'd better use your favorite scripting language to do such thing.

Comment: @Toto, the questioner specifically named the tools allowed :)  This is probably a one-off, if it was a regular task I'd agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a regular expression to replace all **newlines** with **many spaces and a newline**.  Then use a rectangular mouse selection to cut off everything to the right of the width you want.  Not sure if notepad++ copes so well with large rectangular selections though, you might have to do it in several smaller chunks.

Just tried this and it does appear to work.  Select "Regular Expressions" in the replace dialog.  Replace `$` with lots of spaces.  Then use left-ALT+ mouse drag to select all the extra spaces you want to remove on the end of the lines.  Then hit delete.

Comment: What you have mentioned is way to delete white spaces but i need to add white spaces and increase the file length

Comment: @Subha8, Please read it again.  My answer adds lots of spaces and then deletes the surplus.  It'll make sense if you try it.  Adding the spaces to begin with make all lines longer than needed, but they are different lengths.  The rectangular selection makes them all the same length after deleting.